# How to get creation date and time of a deb package on deb repo

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, repository, deb

I need to find out the latest version of a package on deb repo.
Below you will see 0.8.0.13 and 0.8.0.20 versions. In between these release versions there are 0.8.0-debug.XXX builds.
I want to get the deb packages in order by creation time.

[image]

In this picture it is listing on apache web server but I need to get the list using by command line tools such as apt, dpkg etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
apt policy replace_this_with_package_name
apt-get changelog replace_this_with_package_name
```

https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt

https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get